# Refiner and Illuminator badges confusing

Tags: discussion, badges

When I first joined the site, I thought the [Refiner](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/441/refiner) and [Illuminator](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/442/illuminator) badges were impossible. They say "Edit and answer $X$ questions (both actions within $12$ hours...)"

$50$ for Refiner; $500$ for Illuminator.

Is it me or do these descriptions seem a little off? It reads as though one must edit and answer $X$ questions all within a $12$ hour timespan.

Imagine editing and answering $500$ questions in one $12$ hour timespan.

Comment: Editing and answering (with positive score) 500 questions is already a non-trivial task. So in 12 hours, it is indeed unlikely that anybody could do it. Note that *only* [9 persons](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/442/illuminator) have the illuminator badge for the moment. However, I think it is a good practice, *when needed*, to improve the formatting and tagging of a question when you answer it. (Moreover, since you probably more on the subject than the OP, you're likely to know better what is the appropriate tagging.)

Comment: It is worth pointing out that the current description is already a result of an attempt to make it more clear than the original one. See [Description for Explainer, Refiner, Illuminator is unclear](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240299/description-for-explainer-refiner-illuminator-is-unclear) on meta.SE. But it seems that the main concern there was to clarify that both actions must be on the same question.

Answer (score 6):

The word  [both](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Aboth) refers to **two** things. One would not say

> She edited 500 questions, both within 12 hours.

The correct way of expressing that would be

> She edited 500 questions, all within 12 hours.

But the description says "both", which can only refer to making an edit and answering within the same 12-hour interval.

Comment: The current description is even stronger than this, it's says "both actions".And "50 questions" aren't an action.

Answer (score 4):

For *each* question, both action should be done within 12 hours for it to count. You don't have do all 50 or 500 questions in 12 hours.

Comment: I do not think this answers the question. I might be wrong but based on what the OP wrote I think that: A) They understand how these two badges work. B) They also think that the description can be interpreted differently (and maybe it should be improved). As I am not a native speaker, I do not fell competent to judge whether the wording of the tag description is misleading.